# PasswordEncoderNotFoundException using Jira SOAP API

Tags: c#, asp.net, jira, atlassian-crowd

I am working on integrating my company's product with Jira so users can log bug reports directly from the application.  Everything was wqorking smoothly so i decided to import the data from our live Jira system into my development system so that i had some real world data to play with.  Since then when i try to get an authtication token it throws the following exception "com.atlassian.crowd.exception.PasswordEncoderNotFoundException: The PasswordEncoder 'atlassian-security' was not found in the Internal Encoders list by the PasswordEncoderFactory".  I have checked and the Atlassian Security Password Encoder is enabled in the Crown Password Encoders plugin.

My code is super simple just an ASP.net based text based issues search with the results wired to a grid view code as below:

```
JiraSoapServiceService service = new JiraSoapServiceService();

string token = service.login("integration", "test");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
{
   RemoteIssue[] issues = service.getIssuesFromTextSearchWithLimit(token, txtSearch.Text, 0, 100);
   gvwIssues.DataSource = issues;
   gvwIssues.DataBind();
}
```

I get the error on the call to service.login, it worked fine before I imported the live data.  And yes i did add the integration user again after i had imported the data.

Anyone any ideas on this.

Comment: Do the two JIRA instances have the same version?

Comment: No they don't, the live is 4.3 and the dev is 4.4.  However the problem went away when i rebooted the dev machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what was causing this but rebooting the PC that the dev Jira was installed on fixed it.

EDIT

I have had this a few times now.  It tends to happen when you do something like restart the SQL server, restore the jira database via SQL server, restore jira via the inbuilt XML file import method or similar.  You don't have to restart the machine just the jira windows service.  No idea if this is a problem with other DBs or server types.

Comment: I was having this issue as well with our SOAP integration to JIRA. I tried Ben's suggestion above and it did indeed resolve the issue, just restart the JIRA server. Thanks mate!